# Convergence of infinite series after integration

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I am trying to compute the integral of the product between an infinite sum and a function:
$$
I(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(t) f(t) dt 
$$
I know that the series converges and $\int_0^{\infty} | \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(t) f(t) | dt < \infty$, so I am applying Fubini's theorem to perform the integral first:
$$
I(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^{\infty} A_n(t) f(t) dt 
$$
However, after my calculation, I obtain a new infinite series that diverges.

My question: is it possible to obtain a new divergent series after the steps I did or something must be wrong with my calculation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) Your whole post will be more readable if you replace everywhere $A_n(t)f(t)$ by $B_n(t).$ 2) Fubini does not say that if $\lim f_n$ is integrable then its integral is $\lim\int f_n.$

Comment: So, if I understand your comment correctly, my calculation could be right and the result I obtain could very well be divergent?

Comment: I wrote it like this because I know that $A_n$ is convergent but I haven't shown that $B_n(t) = A_n(t) f(t)$ is convergent. But I know that the integral is bounded.

Comment: Yes the result you obtain "could very well be divergent", if you do not have the [required assumption to apply the DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Discussion_of_the_assumptions).

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment, beginning with "I wrote it like this". If $\sum a_n$ is convergent then obviously $\sum a_nc$ is convergent. Hence if $\sum A_n$ is (pointwise) convergent, so is $\sum B_n.$

Comment: the problem is that Fubini requires the absolute convergence wr to the product measure which here comes down to the integrability of the absolute series $\int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty |A_n(t) f(t) | dt < \infty$

Comment: Yes, or if you apply the DCT, you do not need $\sum|B_n|$ to be integrable but still, you need some integrable function $C$ such that $\forall n,\forall t\quad|\sum_{k\le n}B_k(t)|\le C(t).$

Comment: ok, I have shown that $\int_0^\infty | \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(t) f(t) | dt < \infty$ but I am pretty sure  $\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty | A_n(t) f(t) | dt$ does not converge, so, in that case, Fubini cannot be applied, correct?

Comment: Correct. And even DCT cannot be applied, if the (weaker) condition I mentionned is not fulfilled either.

Comment: Thank you for your help!